# Trying to draw an arc over a circle using d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Would like to draw a circle with a concentric arc over it. Using [**D3**](http://d3js.org/). 
This is what I have so far, I can't figure out how to get them how to align over each-other. Here is a pen of what it looks like currently [pen](http://codepen.io/alphalink/pen/WrQrmr).

```
    var h = 138;
    var w = 300;
    var svgProfile = d3.select(".profileWidget p").append("svg").attr("width", w).attr("height", h);
    var dataset = [25];
    var circles = svgProfile.selectAll("circle").data(dataset).enter().append("circle");
    circles.attr("cx", function(d, i) {
            return (i * 50) + 150;
        }).attr("cy", h / 2).attr("r", function(d) {
            return d * 2;
        }).attr("fill", "#6a9b16")
        .attr("stroke", "#2B303B")
        .attr("stroke-width", function(d) {
            return d / 2;
        });
    var svg = d3.select(".profileWidget p")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(110,1)");

    var arc = d3.svg.arc()
        .innerRadius(50)
        .outerRadius(70)
        .startAngle(0)
        .endAngle(1.3 * Math.PI);

    svg.append("path")
        .attr("class", "arc")
        .attr("d", arc)
        .attr('fill', '#1bc');
```

Comment: Please have a minimal example, include either a [*snippet*](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) or a [*fiddle*](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek thank you, I have updated.

Comment: @alphapilgrim, done a pen for you , mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mate, you can just use arc 2 to select the first arc,

```
var svg2 = d3.select("svg")
.append("svg")
.attr("width", 200)
.attr("height", 200)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(100,100)");
```

have done a pen for you: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VevaZg

Comment: @alphapilgrim, no problem mate, happy coding!